# Creating dummy content for Joomla3 component

Tags: php, mysql, joomla3.0

I'm creating Joomla3 component and I need to create some dummy content during the installation, I know that I can use sql file to fill the tables, but this works mainly for custom created tables specific for my component. Problem arises when I want to add something to the #__content table, the 'alias' column isn't considered as unique and there can occur duplicate entries, if someone tries to install the component several times. 
I would like to know what is the best way to insert a record into #__content table without worrying about collateral damage like duplicate entries. 
Thanks all !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1 :
You can use `INSERT IGNORE` so that while installing extension multiple times there will be no concern of duplicate entries.

Solution 2 : 
In Joomla there is a provision of script file which a component can have.

So, when an extension is installed/update/uninstall joomla triggers or calls certain predefined function like install, update, preflight, postflight etc available in the extension script file.

You can add `install method` in your extension script and execute this sql file on this method so that this will not be called on extension update case

Solution 3 :
You can maintain a separate table in your database for this task and when you perform this dummy content creation you can mark this in your DB and further you can check whether this step has already done or not before initiating dummy content creation so that when someone install this extension multiple times this checking will prevent the same task to execute again and again.

Comment: Solution 1. I'm afraid this wouldn't work because the only column checked for duplicates is primary key 'id' and I'm inserting new record without this field (there's autoincrement, so it will be created automatically). Because the 'alias' field isn't restricted with UNIQUE it won't create any error message for the IGNORE instruction, in the end it will create additional record with the same data.

I think I will go with something similar to Solution 3, I will need to check, if this data import process was already executed and then decide what to do. 
Thanks for help !

Comment: insert ignore will work with unique columns only so if there is no column in the table which is unique than this solution will not work for you.
glad to help :)